# Insert into Sharepoint list from pnp with React

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to insert some data (FirstName and SurName) into a Sharepoint list based on what the user enters into Input fields.  I found this page https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items

I found this code, but the values are hard coded rather than being user inputted.  How do I get it to read the FirstName and SurName fields from the input boxes?
    
    `pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("PeopleFields").items.add({
    Title: Util.getGUID(),
    User1Id: 9, // allows a single user
    User2Id: { 
        results: [ 16, 45 ] // allows multiple users
    }
    }).then(i => {
    console.log(i);
    });`

Here are my labels and input boxes.
    
            `{<label>First Name</label>}
        {<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"></input>}
        <p></p>
        {<label>SurName</label>}
        {<input id="SurName" name="SurName" type="text"></input>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use [SPFx-OfficeUIFabric-PeoplePicker](https://github.com/giuleon/SPFx-OfficeUIFabric-PeoplePicker) so you could input people into the control instead of textbox.

You could check the demo below to insert user to list.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pnp-people-picker-control-for-spfx/

Comment: I need to suffix the fieldname with Id

  @autobind
  private addSelectedUsers(): void {  
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("AlistairTest").items.add({
      Title: getGUID(),
      FirstName:"Text",
      PersonNameId: {
          results: this.state.addUsers
      }